# What is the difference in the usage between "reservieren" and "buchen"?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between *reservieren* and *buchen*? Don't they both mean *to book*?

> Ich reserviere eine Reise.
>   Ich buche eine Reise.

Comment: The meaning does overlap to some degree, but it's really much like the difference between "book" and "reserve" (or "put on hold") in English.

Comment: @ingmar *to put on hold* heißt aber eher *etwas aussetzen*, *in Wartestellung bringen*, *auf Eis legen*. *Reservieren* wird als *to reserve* oder *to allocate* (für Ressourcen) übersetzt.

Comment: Es hängt wie immer vom Kontext ab: meine Bücherei, wenn sie mir ein Buch reserviert, _puts it on hold_.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Buchen* often includes a higher grade of commitment, maybe even already paying for it. If you *buchen* something, it normally is yours - if you *reservieren* it, you often only prebooked it. Sometimes you then need to get it in a certain time or you loose your *Reservierung*.

*Reservieren* is very often used in context of seats (like in theaters or trains) or when you want someone to set something aside for you (e.g. in stores). *Buchen* is often used for holidays, including flights and rooms - or if you engage someone (like a singer or a DJ for a party).

*Buchen* normally includes some kind of contract and often includes a penalty fee if you step back, *Reservieren* normally doesn't.

So in your example, I would say that *Ich reserviere eine Reise* is a bit unusual. Maybe you would say *Ich reserviere mir die Zeit für eine Reise*, but if you get your tickets and your rooms, you probably would say *Ich buche eine Reise*.

Comment: If the airline does overbook your flight and you don't get a seat because of that, the airline has not fulfilled their part of the contract and has to give you compensation as defined in the contract. So it's not just a Reservation.

Answer (score 9):

The difference is about the same as in English.

*Etwas reservieren* means that you express your interest in it, blocking it for other people who are also interested. Such a *Reservierung* most of the time is only valid for a certain period of time.

*Etwas buchen* means that you make a definitive statement about your interest. Most of the time this is a binding statement for both parties (the person offering the service and the person who books the service), which you can only withdraw paying some kind of fee.

An example would be: You're interested in a holiday apartement, but you have to ask your spouse first, so you place *eine Reservierung*, talk to your spouse and after that *buchst du* the apartement.